# How to show limited text and remove html tags in Larave blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel.
I am using `{{ Str::limit($leave->leave_reasone, 50) }}` to show limited Text And
`{!! $leave->leave_reasone !!}` to remove Html Tags. But
How can I apply Both in laravel blade?

Answer (score 0):

you can use limit inside [`{!! !!}`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data). both `{{ }}` and `{!! !}}` print variables inside them. the difference is `{{ }}` uses PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks while `{!! !}}` is used to print unescaped data.

```
{!! Str::limit($leave->leave_reasone, 50) !!}
```